# Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource when using web api

Tags: angular

I try to put material table using web api data

my response look like :

```
{
    "Code": "1",
    "Message": "Role List",
    "Data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Employee"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Admin"
        } 
    ]
}
```

when i try to run code i have this "Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource"

my html file:

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="listUsers" class="mat-elevation-z8">
 <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    
  
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
```

my component.ts file :

```
export interface User {   name: string;  id: number;  }const ELEMENT_DATA: User[] = [];


export class ListCompanyComponent implements OnInit  
{
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name' ]; 
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;  
  listUsers :User[]=[];
  constructor(private CommonService:CommonService){}
  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getalldata();
 }
 getalldata()
 {
   this.CommonService.listUsers().subscribe(data=>{
   this.listUsers=data;
  })
 }
}
```

my servicefile :

```
  listUsers():Observable<User[]>
  {
     return this.http.get<User[]>(this.LURL + 'users')
   }
```

how to overcome this issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response is consist of `Code`, `Message`, and `Data`, but clearly what you want to pass to the `dataSource` is the `Data` part only
So you can modify the `getalldata()` method and use `data.Data` instead of `data` to achieve your goal

```js
{
   this.CommonService.listUsers().subscribe(data=>{
   this.listUsers= data.Data;
  })
```

**EDIT:**
You need also to change the type for `listUsers()` to receive `any` or maybe you can make an interface with your actual response that contains `Code`, `Message`, and `Data` and pass it as the type for your method

```js
listUsers():Observable<any>
  {
     return this.http.get<any>(this.LURL + 'users')
   }
```

Comment: i want to get Data only with out that code and message...how i get only data inside getalldata()

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, use `data.Data` instead of `data`

Comment: Property 'Data' does not exist on type 'User[]'. in ts file

Comment: yes now i changed my code as you said but it shows error like Property 'Data' does not exist on type 'User[]'.

Comment: Yes you need to change the return type for `listUsers()` in your service. I will update my answer

Comment: yes i updated service file also

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: now its working.... thank you ... i changed my service file you said it is working perfect